# Spark streaming get data from Twitter and save to Cassandra

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

As mention my question i have a problem about it

Specifically my problem is connect with cassandra and coming data with streaming type.Because i have already connect cassandra and spark and also getting data from twitter.I did this,but seperatly.Now i want to when i getting data from twitter,write this a table which one keyspace.How can i do this?

My codes are there.

```
     val conf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
  .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "5000")
  .setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("myapp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

val tweetsA = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, Array("searchword"))


val tweets_mystring = tweetsA.filter(_.getText.contains("searchword2")).map(ttext => ttext.getText)
tweets_mystring.map(??????).saveToCassandra("mykeyspace", "mytable")
//i can't write my map function like where ????

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(60000)
ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
} 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hey a little late on the response, but I would look into DataStax. It supports the combination of Spark Streaming and Cassandra really well. Easy to use software for streaming data into Cassandra and will continue to be supported as they currently have around $190 Million in investment money. Below is a quick example of it's use.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSave.html